# Writing report in Word, matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to write a report using matlab.

During program I 'm getting a number of figures.I 'm saving all the figures as jpg. 
 These figures and company logo along with some text should appear in the report.

Question is how to paste all these images in a Word document using matlab .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) projects to do just this task.

Check out [Word Report](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17953-wordreport), which includes some demo code. This uses the same active-X interface described in other posts, wrapped in Matlab.

Answer (score 3):

Investigate Matlab's `publish` function which offers to write `doc` format files.  It's a while since I used this but it used to work OK.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to Word or to Excel using the `actxserver` command, for example

```
wd = actxserver('Word.Application')
xl = actxserver('Excel.Application')
```

You can then communicate with Word or Excel to create a new document, insert text and numbers, and copy and insert MATLAB graphics into a report. There's a lot to learn about how to control Word or Excel, but you could start by typing `wd.` or `xl.` and hitting the `tab` key in MATLAB - this will show you the methods you have available to you, such as the `AddWorksheet` method and setting the `Range.Value` property of a cell. Also refer to the Microsoft [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for interacting with Excel (there's a similar one for Word).

The reason I keep mentioning Excel is that I've tried both, and I can pretty much guarantee you'll find it easier with Excel than Word. Note that with recent versions of Office, either can save to a PDF. If you specifically need Word, I've found the easiest way is to manually make a template Word report that includes some identifiable markers for where you want to insert things; then in MATLAB, open up a copy of the template, and iterate through your markers, replacing with the things you want to insert.

Hope that helps!